# How MPTCP closed connection?

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, layer4, transport-protocol

how MPTCP connection with more than one subflow closed? what would happen to MPTCP connection if a client decide to close one of the subflows? it would be very kind of you if you explain it step by step in details

Comment: Smells like homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is clearly explained in [*RFC 6824, TCP Extensions for Multipath Operation with Multiple Addresses*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6824):

> **2.6. Closing an MPTCP Connection**
>
> When Host A wants to inform Host B that it has no more data to send,
> it signals this "Data FIN" as part of the Data Sequence Signal (see
> above). It has the same semantics and behavior as a regular TCP FIN,
> but at the connection level. Once all the data on the MPTCP
> connection has been successfully received, then this message is
> acknowledged at the connection level with a DATA_ACK. Further details
> are in [Section 3.3.3.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6824#section-3.3.3)
>
> ```
>   Host A                                 Host B
>   ------                                 ------
>   DATA_SEQUENCE_SIGNAL      ->
>   [Data FIN]
>
>                             <-           (MPTCP DATA_ACK)
> ```

-and-

> **3.3.3. Closing a Connection**
>
> In regular TCP, a FIN announces the receiver that the sender has no
> more data to send. In order to allow subflows to operate independently
> and to keep the appearance of TCP over the wire, a FIN in MPTCP only
> affects the subflow on which it is sent. This allows nodes to exercise
> considerable freedom over which paths are in use at any one time. The
> semantics of a FIN remain as for regular TCP; i.e., it is not until
> both sides have ACKed each other's FINs that the subflow is fully
> closed.
>
> When an application calls close() on a socket, this indicates that it
> has no more data to send; for regular TCP, this would result in a FIN
> on the connection. For MPTCP, an equivalent mechanism is needed, and
> this is referred to as the DATA_FIN.
>
> A DATA_FIN is an indication that the sender has no more data to send,
> and as such can be used to verify that all data has been successfully
> received. A DATA_FIN, as with the FIN on a regular TCP connection, is
> a unidirectional signal.
>
> The DATA_FIN is signaled by setting the 'F' flag in the Data Sequence
> Signal option (Figure 9) to 1. A DATA_FIN occupies 1 octet (the final
> octet) of the connection-level sequence space. Note that the DATA_FIN
> is included in the Data-Level Length, but not at the subflow level:
> for example, a segment with DSN 80, and Data-Level Length 11, with
> DATA_FIN set, would map 10 octets from the subflow into data sequence
> space 80-89, the DATA_FIN is DSN 90; therefore, this segment including
> DATA_FIN would be acknowledged with a DATA_ACK of 91.
>
> Note that when the DATA_FIN is not attached to a TCP segment
> containing data, the Data Sequence Signal MUST have a subflow sequence
> number of 0, a Data-Level Length of 1, and the data sequence number
> that corresponds with the DATA_FIN itself. The checksum in this case
> will only cover the pseudo-header.
>
> A DATA_FIN has the semantics and behavior as a regular TCP FIN, but at
> the connection level. Notably, it is only DATA_ACKed once all data has
> been successfully received at the connection level. Note, therefore,
> that a DATA_FIN is decoupled from a subflow FIN. It is only
> permissible to combine these signals on one subflow if there is no
> data outstanding on other subflows. Otherwise, it may be necessary to
> retransmit data on different subflows. Essentially, a host MUST NOT
> close all functioning subflows unless it is safe to do so, i.e., until
> all outstanding data has been DATA_ACKed, or until the segment with
> the DATA_FIN flag set is the only outstanding segment.
>
> Once a DATA_FIN has been acknowledged, all remaining subflows MUST be
> closed with standard FIN exchanges. Both hosts SHOULD send FINs on all
> subflows, as a courtesy to allow middleboxes to clean up state even if
> an individual subflow has failed. It is also encouraged to reduce the
> timeouts (Maximum Segment Life) on subflows at end hosts. In
> particular, any subflows where there is still outstanding data queued
> (which has been retransmitted on other subflows in order to get the
> DATA_FIN acknowledged) MAY be closed with a RST.
>
> A connection is considered closed once both hosts' DATA_FINs have been
> acknowledged by DATA_ACKs.
>
> As specified above, a standard TCP FIN on an individual subflow only
> shuts down the subflow on which it was sent. If all subflows have been
> closed with a FIN exchange, but no DATA_FIN has been received and
> acknowledged, the MPTCP connection is treated as closed only after a
> timeout. This implies that an implementation will have TIME_WAIT
> states at both the subflow and connection levels (see [Appendix
> C](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6824#appendix-C)). This permits "break-before-make" scenarios where connectivity
> is lost on all subflows before a new one can be re- established.